# Проблема в Discord Rich Presence Status. Не отображаются две кнопки

Tags: javascript

Написал вот такой код, всё работает кроме этих кнопок. Как это исправить?

```
const clientId = '/'
const DiscordRPC = require('discord-rpc')
const RPC = new DiscordRPC.Client({ transport: 'ipc' })

DiscordRPC.register(clientId)


async function setActivity() {
    let RandomInt= Math.floor(Math.random() * 111010);
    if (!RPC) return;
    RPC.setActivity({
            state : "/",
            details : "/",
            largeImageKey : "https://media.tenor.com/_sRq7f0tQLEAAAAC/reactjs.gif", 
            largeImageText : "/",
            smallImageKey : "URL link",
            smallImageText : "Text",
            partyid: "/",
            partySize: RandomInt,
            partyMax: 111010,
        buttons : [
            {label : "Мой Steam." , url : "/"}, 
            {label : "Мой WebSite.",url : "/"},       
        ]

    })

}

RPC.on('ready', async () => {
    setActivity()

    setInterval(() => {
        setActivity()

    },
        3 * 1000)
})


RPC.login({clientId}).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let rpc = require("discord-rpc")
let token = '/'
const client = new rpc.Client({ transport: 'ipc' })

async function getEllemet() {
    let RandomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 111010);
        client.request('SET_ACTIVITY', {
            pid: process.pid,
            activity: {
                state: "/",
                details: "/",
                assets: {
                    large_image: "/",
                    large_text: "/",
                    small_image: "/",
                    small_text: "/",
                },
                party: {
                    "id": "/",
                    "size": [RandomInt, 111010]
                },
                timestamps: {
                    start: 1,
                    //end: 6,

                },
                buttons: [
                    {label: "Мой Steam.", url: "/"},
                    {label: "Мой WebSite.", url: "/"},
                ]
            }
        })
   }


client.on('ready',async () => {
    getEllemet()

    setInterval(() => {
            getEllemet()
        },
        3 * 1000)
})


client.login({ clientId : token }).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Если кому надо, то берите. Только заместо "/" своё.